# Why does Entity Framework return null object?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nullreferenceexception, ado.net-entity-data-model

I have a project and use Entity Framework to work with database.
I get this error when I want to get list of entity.

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Code:

```
var query = db.FSefareshArt
              .Where(se => se.SefareshID == intSefareshId)
              .ToList()
              .Select(se => new { se.ArtID, se.KalaID, se.Kala.KalaName, se.Kala.Abead, se.Count, se.Kala.Vahed, se.SefareshID, se.Person.FullName, se.ArtStateID, StateTitle = Upset.GetSefArtState(se.ArtID), se.Description, se.CreationDateTime })
              .ToList();
```

When I run the project, it works without error, but when I insert a new record, this error happens.

Entity `Kala` in `se.Kala` is null. Why?

Comment: You need to include "Kala". For example `db.FSefareshArt.Include("Kala").Where(...).Select(...).ToList()`